# Link url paths change from within the 'user' area

Tags: navigation

I have made a block for a footer which contains 2 simple links. The html code is as follows:

```
<div class="privacyTerms">
<a href="privacy">PRIVACY-POLICY</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="terms">TERMS &amp; CONDITIONS</a>
</div>
```

The links work fine as long as i click on them while being anywhere on the website BESIDES the user profile. BUT, as soon as i try to click the links while in my user profile, instead of the URL pointing to "/privacy" or "/terms", the system appends a "/user/" path before the link. So the link becomes as follows: "/user/privacy" and "/user/terms". If i try to access it i get a Access denied. 
I cannot for the life of me! figure out why this is happening.....
What am i missing?
Drupal 7

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `href` from

```
<a href="privacy">
```

and

```
<a href="terms">
```

to

```
<a href="/privacy">
```

and

```
<a href="/terms">
```

Notice the slash. That means the path is relative to your base url instead of being relative to your current path.

Answer (score 0):

Use href value like this

```
<a href="<?php echo url('terms');?>">TERMS &amp; CONDITIONS</a>
```

It will work everywhere.